# Row selection code in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Suppose I have different `tables` in different `jsp pages`. I have to write a generic code in `jQuery` so that on each `page` when I `click` on any place in a particular row the whole `row` gets selected and its `color` changes. Please help!

```
<html>
<body>
<table border = 1 align="center" width="500" height="50">
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

For example above is my table.Now please suggest how to do?I am new all this.

Comment: at least show us your html

Comment: Voting to close :Too broad.

Comment: @Chris, I have given a sample html.Now please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```
.highlight{background-color:red;}
```

JS:

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```